# Expose public and private endpoint through Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway like entrypoint for my infrastructure. The gateway is configured with keycloak to validate Authentication header with following configuration

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource-server:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://httpd.keycloak.local:443/keycloak/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

An example Route is the following

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: my-route
          uri: http://service.local:8020
          predicates:
            - Path=/myPath/api/myRoute/test
          filters:
            - name: StripPrefix
              args:
                parts: 2
```

How can I define, into yml file, this route public and another one authenticated through jwk-uri directed to keycloak?

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing about security rules in spring-cloud-gateway [configuration doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/).

I believe you'll have to either:

- let all traffic go through gateway and handle security on each service
- write a web-security configuration class and define a [SecurityWebFilterChain  bean](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/2b852a95fcf8ca849eaf8c546b2be5b2d18dfc37/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/reactive/ReactiveSecurityBeans.java#L242).
- use [spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server) to define `permitAll()` routes  from properties (other routes requirering user to be authenticated)

Only last solution would work with yaml file configuration only:
in pom, replace `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` with

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>${com.c4-soft.springaddons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

in yaml, replace `spring.security.oauth2.resource-server` with

```yaml
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security:
  jwt-issuers:
    - location: https://httpd.keycloak.local:443/keycloak/realms/myRealm
  permit-all:
    - /myPath/api/myRoute/test
    - /public/**
```

Note that trying to access "non-public" routes without valid authorization would result in 401 (unauthorized) and not in 302 (redirect to login). In my opinion, client should unsure requests to protected routes are issued with `Authorization` header or handle unauthorized with a redirection to authorization-server and a retry.

Also note that `spring-security-oauth2-webflux-addons` will auto-configure more than just permit-all routes (CORS, CSRF and authorities mapping for instance).

Last, I haven't tried it yet with spring-cloud-gateway. please let me know how it goes ;-)